# Sort [NSDictionary allKeys] alphabetically

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting

I'm developing an iOS 5.0+ app with latest SDK.

I want to show a `UIPickerView` with a list of countries. These countries will be sorted alphabetically. And when the user select a country, I have to stored its ISO Code.

This is the code I'm using now to get countries' names localized:

```
+ (NSArray*)countriesNames
{
    NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
    NSArray *countryArray = [NSLocale ISOCountryCodes];

    NSMutableArray *sortedCountryArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (NSString *countryCode in countryArray)
    {
        NSString* displayNameString = [locale displayNameForKey:NSLocaleCountryCode
                                                          value:countryCode];
        [sortedCountryArray addObject:displayNameString];
    }
    [sortedCountryArray sortUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCompare:)];

    return sortedCountryArray;
}
```

But, I need to use something, for example, a `NSDictionary`; that let me know get ISO Code and localized name.

I have tried to use a `NSDictionary` instead of a `NSArray`:

```
+ (NSDictionary*)countriesNames
{
    NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
    NSArray *countryArray = [NSLocale ISOCountryCodes];

    NSMutableDictionary* sortedCountryDic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    for (NSString *countryCode in countryArray)
    {
        NSString* displayNameString = [locale displayNameForKey:NSLocaleCountryCode
                                                          value:countryCode];
        [sortedCountryDic setObject:countryCode forKey:displayNameString];

    }

    [[sortedCountryDic allKeys] sortUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCompare:)];

    return sortedCountryDic;
}
```

But I get a compile time exception: `No visible @interface for 'NSArray' declares the selector 'sortUsingSelector:'`.

Here:

```
[[sortedCountryDic allKeys] sortUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCompare:)];
```

**How can I sort allKeys?**
**Is there any way to get ISOCode using its displayName?**

Comment: Why would you use the country name as the dictionary instead of the country code?

Comment: it could happen, because the `-sortUsingSelector:` is a method of an `NSMutableArray` class only. the `NSArray` has the `-sortedArrayUsingSelector:` method instead, and method `allKeys` rather returns an `NSArray` than `NSMutableArray` object.

Answer (score 2):

sortUsingSelector: is a method of NSMutableArray not a method of NSArray
you can use sortedArrayUsingSelector to sort the array, and you will get a new array with sorted contents

```
- (NSArray *)sortedArrayUsingSelector:(SEL)comparator


+ (NSArray*)countriesNames
{
    NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
    NSArray *countryArray = [NSLocale ISOCountryCodes];

    NSMutableDictionary* sortedCountryDic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    for (NSString *countryCode in countryArray)
    {
        NSString* displayNameString = [locale displayNameForKey:NSLocaleCountryCode
                                                          value:countryCode];
        [sortedCountryDic setObject:countryCode forKey:displayNameString];

    }

    return [[sortedCountryDic allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCompare:)];    
}
```

Comment: This method returns an `NSArray` but its return type is declared as `NSDictionary`.